# Bootstrap multiple dropdown menus

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get a bootstrap navbar to split into two independent drop-down menus when on small screens, one of the menus will have the languages with a tiny flag and the rest will have the actual menu pages. I can't seem to get this to work since they either drop the same menu or only one of them works. I don't need to work with the below, it is just a mockup. Thanks!!

```
<?php  /* Navigation: Start */  ?>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Trust</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only"></span>
                <img class="abe-language-flags-menu" src="images/flags/4x3/us.svg">
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index">Trust</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onmousedown="toggleOverlay()">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="#hotels">Hotels</a></li>
                <li><a href="#rooms">Rooms</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Language<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="language">
                            <a class="abe-language-name" href="#">English </a>
                            <img class="abe-language-flags img-rounded" src="images/flags/4x3/us.svg">
                        </li>
                        <li class="language">
                            <a class="abe-language-name" href="#">German  </a>
                            <img class="abe-language-flags img-rounded" src="images/flags/4x3/de.svg">
                        </li>
                        <li class="language">
                            <a class="abe-language-name" href="#">Spanish </a>
                            <img class="abe-language-flags img-rounded" src="images/flags/4x3/es.svg">
                        </li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Other languages</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<?php  /* Navigation: End */  ?>
<?php  /* Navigation: Start */  ?>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Trust</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only"></span>
                <img class="abe-language-flags-menu" src="images/flags/4x3/us.svg">
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index">Trust</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onmousedown="toggleOverlay()">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="#hotels">Hotels</a></li>
                <li><a href="#rooms">Rooms</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Language<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="language">
                            <a class="abe-language-name" href="#">English </a>
                            <img class="abe-language-flags img-rounded" src="images/flags/4x3/us.svg">
                        </li>
                        <li class="language">
                            <a class="abe-language-name" href="#">German  </a>
                            <img class="abe-language-flags img-rounded" src="images/flags/4x3/de.svg">
                        </li>
                        <li class="language">
                            <a class="abe-language-name" href="#">Spanish </a>
                            <img class="abe-language-flags img-rounded" src="images/flags/4x3/es.svg">
                        </li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Other languages</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: It is my code. I just meant that I can discard ;)

Answer (score 0):

This might help or give you some ideas: you can completely split the navigation into two parts; one standard navbar for the general links and one that's always a dropdown for the languages.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 125px;
}
.navbar.navbar-default {
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
}
.navbar-default.nav-lower {
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.navbar-default.nav-lower .navbar-toggle,
.navbar-default.nav-lower .navbar-toggle:focus,
.navbar-default.nav-lower .navbar-toggle:hover {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
}
.navbar-default.nav-lower > li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  text-align: left;
}
.navbar-default.nav-lower .navbar-brand {
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.navbar-default.nav-lower .navbar-toggle span.glyphicon {
  color: #555;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.navbar-default.nav-lower .navbar-nav .abe-language-name img {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
@media (max-width: 2500px) {
  .navbar-default.nav-lower .navbar-header {
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar-default.nav-lower .navbar-left,
  .navbar-default.nav-lower .navbar-right {
    float: none !important;
  }
  .navbar-default.nav-lower .navbar-toggle,
  .navbar-default.nav-lower .navbar-toggle:hover,
  .navbar-default.nav-lower .navbar-toggle:focus {
    display: block;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    padding-right: 20px;
  }
  .navbar-default.nav-lower .navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  }
  .navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top {
    top: 0;
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
  }
  .navbar-default.nav-lower .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .navbar-default.nav-lower .navbar-nav {
    float: none !important;
    margin-top: 7.5px;
  }
  .navbar-default.nav-lower .navbar-nav > li {
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar-default.nav-lower .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .navbar-default.nav-lower .collapse.in {
    display: block !important;
  }
  .navbar-default.nav-lower .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  .navbar-default.nav-lower .navbar-collapse {
    text-align: left;
    background: #f5f5f5;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 767px) {
  .navbar.nav-lower .navbar-toggle,
  .navbar.nav-lower .navbar-toggle:focus,
  .navbar.nav-lower .navbar-toggle:hover {
    margin-right: 30px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Trust</a>

    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="bs-navbar">
      <!-- Non-collapsing right-side icons -->
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#" onmousedown="toggleOverlay()">Login</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#hotels">Hotels</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#rooms">Rooms</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default nav-lower">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-lower-nav" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Select a Language</a>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-lower-nav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="language">
          <a class="abe-language-name" href="#">
            <img class="abe-language-flags img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/20x20/f00/f00">English</a>

        </li>
        <li class="language">
          <a class="abe-language-name" href="#">
            <img class="abe-language-flags img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/20x20/f00/f00">German</a>

        </li>
        <li class="language">
          <a class="abe-language-name" href="#">
            <img class="abe-language-flags img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/20x20/f00/f00">Spanish</a>

        </li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Other languages</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <div class="well">Boostrap Mobile</div>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
    took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
    sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
    printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
    but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
    including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
    it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
    and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since
    the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
    the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
    industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
    typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
    Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
    took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
    sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
    printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
    but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
    including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out, I created independant data-target for navbar and navbar2 and used hidden-xs and hidden-sm etc to make it look good. :) Thanks for the help @vanburenx ASking the question freed my mind to give it another approach ;-)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Trust</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only"></span>
                <img class="abe-language-flags-menu" src="images/flags/4x3/us.svg">
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index">Trust</a>
        </div>

        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onmousedown="toggleOverlay()">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="#hotels">Hotels</a></li>
                <li><a href="#rooms">Rooms</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown hidden-xs">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle hidden-xs" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Language<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="language">
                            <a class="abe-language-name" href="#">English </a>
                            <img class="abe-language-flags img-rounded" src="images/flags/4x3/us.svg">
                        </li>
                        <li class="language">
                            <a class="abe-language-name" href="#">German  </a>
                            <img class="abe-language-flags img-rounded" src="images/flags/4x3/de.svg">
                        </li>
                        <li class="language">
                            <a class="abe-language-name" href="#">Spanish </a>
                            <img class="abe-language-flags img-rounded" src="images/flags/4x3/es.svg">
                        </li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Other languages</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar2" class="navbar-collapse collapse hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right  hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Change Language<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="language">
                            <a class="abe-language-name" href="#">English </a>
                            <img class="abe-language-flags img-rounded" src="images/flags/4x3/us.svg">
                        </li>
                        <li class="language">
                            <a class="abe-language-name" href="#">German  </a>
                            <img class="abe-language-flags img-rounded" src="images/flags/4x3/de.svg">
                        </li>
                        <li class="language">
                            <a class="abe-language-name" href="#">Spanish </a>
                            <img class="abe-language-flags img-rounded" src="images/flags/4x3/es.svg">
                        </li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Other languages</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```